# C# Right way to update Data using getter and setter in Generic Data (Data : INotifyPropertyChanged)

Tags: c#, datagridview, getter-setter, bindinglist

I am quite new to C# and want to know the right way (not wasting any resources) to handle Generic Data.

I have a BindingList that is used to bind dataGridView.DataSource.

Below is the example code that updates Data values: The question is whether it be more efficient to place the "calculating codes" in the getter or the setter.

If there is an approach to this that would be considered a 'best practice' please let me know that too.

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private float number;
    public string Code
    {
        get => Number; //  get => Number / 100     which one is more efficient?
        set { Number = value / 100; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

... where the **Data** class is used like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<Data> dataList = new BindingList<Data> { new Data { Code = "1"  } };

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        // When main form is ready to handle messages the binding happens.
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        myDataGridView.DataSource = dataList;
        myDataGridView.Columns["Code"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code sample is interesting for pointing out that the underlying field type (in this case __float__) isn't always the same type as the property setting it (in this case __string__) and that we _do_ sometimes have to perform conversions in the {get; set;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: "The question is whether to place "calculating codes" to the getter or not."

A: Short answer: Do the calculation once in the **set** instead of on every **get**.

Long answer:

I notice your 'Code' property is a **string** but the underlying value seems to be a **float**.  That's ok, but I have a few suggestions for optimizing:

1. Obviously, the input string **value** in the 'Code' property setter will have to be parsed at some point in order to perform the float calculation shown in your code. The float.Parse() method *will throw a hard Exception* as written here. Make sure you add some validation code to the input string and fail gracefully if it can't be parsed.
2. To fire the PropertyChanged event, I suggest the form here: use the **nameof** keyword and make OnPropertyChanged protected virtual so that inherited classes can fire the event, too.
3. It's just an opinion of course, but I would do the calculation once in the setter, not the getter. But then if it's stored as a float, I would do the ToString() in the getter.
4. I don't see the harm in a short-running calculation in the setter. If it's some kind of long-running task to perform a calculation, consider using a method instead and possibly doing it asynchronously as a Task.

```
    public string Code
    {
        get => _number.ToString(); // 'Some' inefficiency here, but probably storing as float is preferred.
        set 
        {
            // I would offer that doing this ONCE in the setter
            // is more efficient than calculating on every get.
            float floatValue = float.Parse(value);  // Warning: Will throw exception 
                                                    // is value if unparsable input string
            _number = floatValue / 100;

            // Preferred form here is to use the 'nameof' keyword
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Code)));
        }
    }
    // I suggest some other notation than 'Number' because this
    // is a private field and when you say 'Number' the expectation is 
    // a public property. I see this notation often in Google source code
    // to indicate a 'private field' and have adopted it myself:
    private float _number;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This is customarily 'protected virtual'
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

Since a lot of this has to do with 'style points' there are other perspectives than my own. I do believe there's enough substance to justify posting this answer and hope it provides some insights for the thing you are asking.

Comment: Amazing answer! This is exactly what I wanted especially on your point number 2,3,and 4 and For number 1 it was my mistake, it should be both float with same name. Yes I ended up trying all of three ways and like you said the code runs much faster once I put calculation in methods not in getters and setters Thank you IVSoftware :)

Comment: So glad I could assist!

Comment: If you're digging into DataGridView, there are a few other answers I've written about the subject including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153053/5438626) for starters. There are also more than a dozen Winforms examples on [IVSoftware @ GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware?tab=repositories) that are linked back to StackOverflow questions. You (and everyone) are certainly invited to look around and see if there's anything there you might think is worthwhile.

Comment: @hyukkyulee I would say not so much a 'mistake' - the term I'd use is 'happy accident' because this scenario is _not_ unheard of.

Comment: @IVSoftware I've had problems with using DataGridView in virtual mode. While updating my data (ex: adding/inserting a row), the DataGridView polls CellValueNeeded in the middle of the update, not enabling the background source to be updated (since both can't actually happen in parallel). I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658921/how-to-keep-virtualmode-datagridview-from-calling-cellvalueneeded-while-updating), but have gotten no feedback. In general, I have found the DataGridView control to be very buggy when used in virtual mode.

Comment: Evidence  has it that DGV VirtualMode is non-buggy and delivers good performance if threading and message queues are well understood. You know I worked in automotive IC validation testing.  [1 ppm error way too high](https://c44f5d406df450f4a66b-1b94a87d576253d9446df0a9ca62e142.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/2018/01/10_15-Packaging_ICs_to_Survive_the_Automotive_Environment.pdf) and detecting such errors requires even higher precision. (Sorry to repeat, I know that's in my SO profile...). DGV was our window to a bunch of SQLite databases that held millions of data points to cross-correlate. And it worked.

Comment: @Adam I diagnosed your issue and have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236942/5438626) to your question. If you substitute my code for yours then the Exceptions you describe should no longer be thrown.

Comment: @Adam and IVSoftware  I am also working on virtualization right now and found your comments helpful thanks!

Comment: Hey @hyukkyulee I was pleased to see you (at least I think it's you) following our GutHub feed. So, in other words, you have both the [code](https://github.com/IVSoftware/data-grid-view-virtual-mode-gen-6.git) and the [video](http://ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/data-grid-view-virtual-gen-6.mp4) for that project, yes?

Comment: @IVSoftware Awesome :)))))!! yepp that's me always ready to learn great simple codes